# Straightedge-only construction of segment of length $\sqrt{7}$, given regular hexagon with unit sides

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

> Let's consider a regular hexagon with unit side length. Draw a line segment of length $\sqrt{7}$ using nothing except a straightedge (that is, an unmarked ruler). The position of the segment may be chosen as you wish.

My thoughts: I've drawn all sorts of lines and tried to get the segment in one of the inside triangles, but to no avail.

Comment: Do you mean a regular hexagon of unit side length?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain your thoughts about the problem so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rectangle that has as basis a diagonal of the hexagon and as height the orthogonal median ( joining mean points of opposite sides) has diagonal = $\sqrt 7$.

[image]

Added after Blue comment.
[image]

All lines can be drown with an unmarked straightedge.

Comment: How do you propose to construct the vertical blue and red lines using only an unmarked straightedge? (With a small adjustment, the basic idea can be salvaged.)

Comment: Use minor diagonals, and it is not difficult.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a variation on @Emilio's answer:

[image]

Extend two hexagon edges to get $A$; then connect $A$ to $B$.